# SQL Server Remove Duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that Tracks Employees and the days they have spent in a policy. I don't generate this Data, it is dumped to our Server Daily.

The table looks like this:

[image: Employees]

My Goal is to get rid of the duplicates by keeping only the most recent Date.
In this example, if I run the query, I would like it to keep Rows 11 for Nicholas Morris and 14 for Tiana Sullivan.

Assumption: First name and Last Name combo are unique

So far,
This is what I have been doing:

```
select *
from 
Employees IN(
    Select ID
    from Employees
    group by FirstName, lastName
    Having count(*) > 1)
```

This returns to me the rows that have duplicates and I have to manually search them and remove the ones I don't want to keep.

I am sure there is a better way of doing this
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete using an `exists` operator where you remove any row that has the same first and last name, but with a newer date:

```sql
DELETE FROM employees e1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   employees e2
               WHERE  e1.FirstName    = e2.FirstName AND
                      e1.LastName     = e2.LastName  AND
                      e1.DaysInPolicy < e2.DaysInPolicy)
```

Comment: this worked for me. Just add e1 after Delete for statement to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE and ROW_NUMBER() function to do it.

The query to get the data is:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName ORDER BY DaysInPolicy DESC) AS Identifier
FROM 
   Employees
```

The query to remove duplicates is:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
     SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() 
     OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName ORDER BY DaysInPolicy DESC) AS Identifier
FROM 
   Employees
)
DELETE E
FROM 
   Employees E
   INNER JOIN CTE C ON C.ID = E.ID
WHERE 
   C.Identifier > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(   
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Last_Name, First_Nmae ORDER BY DaysInPolicy DESC) AS RowNum 
    FROM Employees
) AS Emp
WHERE Emp.RowNum > 1
```

Comment: This yields to the right results as well. Just need to replace the select with "delete" for those who will use it.
Thank you